# Postfix (virtual users) + dovecot + sieve: envelop does not contain original recipient

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I have set up my email server following the [ISPMail tutorial](https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/) with virtual users in postfix + dovecot + sieve. My problem is: the `envelop` "variable" in sieve does not contain the original recipient.

---

I have a mail account, let's call it `mail@example.org` and additional aliases set up for postfix which all deliver to the aforementioned address:

```
name@example.org -> mail@example.org
@domain.com -> mail@example.org
```

The latter being an catch-all address.

Postfix calls dovecot with the following config line in `master.cfg`:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -a ${recipient}
```

With sieve I want to put all mails received for the catch-all address into a specific folder. My sieve code looks like this:

```
if envelope :is :domain "To" "domain.com" {
  fileinto "special-folder";
}
```

This sadly does not work. Digging further I found out that what's inside `envelop` always is the final delivery address, i.e. `mail@example.org` in this case. I found this using the following rule:

```
if envelope :matches "To" "*" {
  fileinto "${1}";
}
```

And the sieve log telling me:

```
failed to store into mailbox 'mail@example.org': Mailbox doesn't exist: mail@example.org.
```

I'm already guessing that this has to be a problem somewhere between postfix and dovecot as the mail log tells me the following:

```
Aug 29 10:38:27 *** dovecot: lda(mail@example.org): sieve: msgid=<54003C01.1080704@***>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Aug 29 10:38:27 *** dovecot: lda(mail@example.org): Error: sieve: execution of script /var/vmail/example.org/mail/dovecot.sieve failed, but implicit keep was successful (user logfile /var/vmail/example.org/mail/dovecot.sieve.log may reveal additional details)
Aug 29 10:38:27 *** postfix/pipe[12469]: A31A28006B: to=<mail@example.org>, orig_to=<test@domain.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.29, delays=0.18/0.01/0/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
```

Obviously postfix states the original recipient (test@domain.com) and the mailbox delivered to (mail@example.org) but somehow this information gets lost on the way to dovecot?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing (the [answer by masegaloeh](https://serverfault.com/a/625184/239976) and the help of a friend provided some useful hints) there are two ways (both seem to work equally good):

1. Use `${original_recipient}` instead of `${recipient}`:

   As [man pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) tells us "*This  macro  expands  to  the  complete recipient address before any address rewriting or aliasing*" so it is the solution to my problem. So the modified command line in `master.cf` should look like

   ```
   dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
     flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -a ${original_recipient}
   ```
2. Use a `X-Original-To` header an tell dovecot to set its envelope to this header field:

   As masegaloeh suggested I add `O` to the flags telling postfix to add the `X-Original-To` header. Inside `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf` I tell dovecot to use this header for its envelope:

   ```
   lda_original_recipient_header = X-Original-To
   ```

   As the comment above this config options tells us, we must not use the `-a` option when calling `dovecot-lda` via postfix because it overrides this setting. Thus the `master.cf` looks like:

   ```
   dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
     flags=DORhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
   ```

Comment: And what about if using LMTP instead LDA?

Comment: I am using `mailbox_command` instead of the `master.cf` entry and I had some issues invalid user bounces when trying to swap `-a` for `-d`. However, just *removing* `-a` worked for me.

Comment: @sebelk it seems postfix still doesn't allow passing X-Original-To via LMTP, so postfix  + dovecot-lmtp + sieve is still not possible (without workarounds which have privacy issues).

Answer (score 3):

This behavior happened because you add `{recipient}` macro in `dovecot-lda` argument. As stated in [man pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html), the postfix will replace that macro with final recipient (mail.example.org) instead of not original ones (test@domain.com).

---

Instead of parsing envelope, you can parsing another header like **X-Original-To**. This header [intended to preserve the original recipient](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) before rewriting or aliasing. To enable this header, edit `master.cf` so the dovecot line become (notice that flag argument was edited)

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -a ${recipient}
```

Then your sieve script become

```
if header :matches "X-Original-To" "*" {
  fileinto "${1}";
}
```

A bit complicated but the result is you can have original recipient and its aliases.

Comment: This sounds good and linking to the pipe manual gave me an even better idea: replacing `${recipient}` by `${original_recipient}` does just what I need.
Hopefully there are no problems with this but after some testing I don't see any.

Comment: Good job @Artemis. You should award your self by accepting your own answer.